# Why Top ,OFFset fetch , Rownumber query gives different outcome just by changing the ascending and descending order?

Tags: database, database-design, database-connection, relational-database, database-schema

Using the `AdventureWorks2012` database

Step 1: Execute the following query :

```
select *
from 
    (select
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER(order by listprice desc) AS RowNumber,*
     from Production.Product) as a
where 
    a.RowNumber between 1 and 2

select *
from Production.Product
order by ListPrice desc
offset 0 rows fetch next 2 rows only

select top 2 Productid, ListPrice
from Production.Product
order by ListPrice desc
```

Step 2: Now execute the following query:

```
select *
from 
    (select
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER(order by listprice asc) AS RowNumber,*
     from Production.Product) as a
where 
     a.RowNumber between 1 and 2

select *
from Production.Product
order by ListPrice asc
offset 0 rows fetch next 2 rows only

select top 2 Productid, ListPrice 
from Production.Product 
order by ListPrice asc
```

View the Product id's in both cases (for DESC and ASC)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not at all surprising.  What you have learned is that multiple rows have the same `listprice` value.  When there are ties for the `listprice`, the ordering is *indeterminate* for keys with the same value.

In other words, sorting in SQL Server (and databases in general) is not stable.  Running the same query multiple times can return different orderings.  Similarly, small changes to a query can result in different orderings -- for keys with the same value.

This is actually really easy to understand.  SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  Hence, they have no *natural* ordering.  There is no way for databases to have a canonical ordering for rows with the same key values.

To fix this, just add a unique id to the ordering, something like:

```
order by listprice desc, productid
```

Adding the additional unique key makes the sort stable.